# Spring specification with custom cross join by simple attribute

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, predicate

Following scenario

```
@Entity("YEAR")
public class Year{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Long name;

    ...
}


@Entity("FOO")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "FK_YEAR", nullable = false)
    public Long yearId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String name;

    ...
}

@Entity("FII")
public class Fii {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "FK_YEAR", nullable = false)
    public Long yearId;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String code;

    ...
}

@Entity("NTOM")
public class NtoM {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "FK_FOO", nullable = false)
    public Long fooId;

    @Column(name = "FK_FII", nullable = false)
    public Long fiiId;

    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
    public Boolean state;

    @Column(name = "VALUES", length = 500)
    public String values;

    ...
}
```

Resulting in an ERP like this:

[image: ERP-NtoM]

I now do have a JpaRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface NtoMRepository extends JpaRepository<NtoM, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<NtoM> {

  String BASE_QUERY =
      "SELECT"
      // prevent jpa to return null instead of id=0
      + " CASE WHEN ntom.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ntom.ID END AS ID ,"
      + " CASE WHEN ntom.STATE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ntom.STATE END AS STATE ,"
      + " ntom.VALUES,"
      + " fii.ID AS FK_FII,"
      + " foo.ID AS FK_FOO "
      + " FROM MYSCHEMA.FOO foo"
      + " INNER JOIN MYSCHEMA.FII fii ON fii.FK_YEAR = foo.FK_YEAR"
      + " OUTER JOIN MYSCHEMA.NTOM ntom ON ntom.FK_FII = fii.ID AND ntom.FK_FOO = foo.ID"

  @Query(value = BASE_QUERY + " WHERE fii.ID = :fiiId", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Option> findByFiiId(@Param("fiiId") Long fiiId);

  @Query(value = BASE_QUERY + " WHERE foo.ID = :fooId", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Option> findByFooId(@Param("fooId") Long fooId);
}
```

So the 2 queries here compute me missing entries whenever I call them, which works out quite nicely.

How could I use the "toPredicate" of the https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ to accomplish this by creating a similar behavior but with dynamic parameters?

I cant just use criteriabuilder "join" as the values are only "basic attributes". Also do I want to reuse the dynamic approach as the "controller endpoint can look like"

```
@GetMapping
public List<NtoM> find(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long id,@RequestParam(value = "fiiId", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long fiiId, @RequestParam(value = "fooId", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long fooId){
    Specification<NtoM> spec = ... //build as AND construct of all parameters (if not null or empty add it)
    // TODO instead of the SELECT * FROM myschema.ntom the custom query here!
    return repo.findAll(spec);
}
```

How can I do this. I can also use the EntityManager and the `criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery()`. But it seems to not work (I cant join the tables as there is no "ManyToOne" between them)

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't there relationships in your domain model? It can be handled efficiently if you change your model to have relationships. Here is how I would approach this problem:

1. Start with creating relationships.

   ```
    @Entity("YEAR")
    public class Year{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public Long name;

        ...
    }


    @Entity("FOO")
    public class Foo {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Long id;

        //@Column(name = "FK_YEAR", nullable = false)
        //public Long yearId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_YEAR", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        public Year year;

        @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public String name;

        ...
    }

    @Entity("FII")
    public class Fii {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Long id;

        //@Column(name = "FK_YEAR", nullable = false)
        //public Long yearId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_YEAR", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        public Year year;

        @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false, length = 10)
        public String code;

        ...
    }

    @Entity("NTOM")
    public class NtoM {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Long id;

        //@Column(name = "FK_FOO", nullable = false)
        //public Long fooId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_FOO", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        public Foo foo;

        //@Column(name = "FK_FII", nullable = false)
        //public Long fiiId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FK_FII", referencedColumnName = "ID")
        public Fii fii;

        @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
        public Boolean state;

        @Column(name = "VALUES", length = 500)
        public String values;

        ...
    }
   ```
2. Change the controller to get the request parameters into map.
   Then delegate the data retrieving logic to the service layer (You can also create custom repository impelementation).

   ```
    @GetMapping
    public List<NtoM> find(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams) {
        return service.findByRequestParams(requestParams);
    }
   ```
3. In the service class

   ```
    public List<NtoM> findByRequestParams(Map<String, String> requestParams) {
        return repository.findAll(createSpec(requestParams));
    }

    private Specification<NtoM> createSpec(Map<String, String> requstParams ) {

    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        Join<NtoM, Fii> firstJoin = root.join("fii", JoinType.INNER);
        Join<NtoM, Foo> secondJoin = fiiJoin("foo", JoinType.LEFT);

        String value = requstParams.get("id");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            Predicate id = criteriaBuilder.equal(secondJoin.get("id"), Long.parseLong(value));
            predicates.add(id);
        }

        value = requestParams.get("fiiId");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            Predicate fii = criteriaBuilder.equal(secondJoin.get("fii"), Long.parseLong(value));
            predicates.add(fii);
        }

        value = requestParams.get("fooId");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            Predicate foo = criteriaBuilder.equal(secondJoin.get("foo"), Long.parseLong(value));
            predicates.add(foo);
        }

        //Later you can add new options without breaking the existing API
        // For example like search by values
        value = requestParams.get("values");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            Predicate likeValues = criteriaBuilder.like(secondJoin.get("values"), "%" + value + "%");
            predicates.add(likeValues);
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        };
    }
   ```

Comment: Sadly there is no opportunity to add the foreign "entity" to the entities class. The objects are used in a "modulare" design architecture which does not care for "side" objects of the context worked on (like a monolithic application). Mapping those entities to some other objects and always mapping them back to the original state would be hell.